# Ordinary kriging tools available in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, interpolation, tools, kriging, geosoft

I have been using Geosoft's Target to interpolate X, Y coordinates then use them to create grids using ordinary kriging.

I am now working with ArcGIS which I am new to and can't seem to be able to interpolate my coordinates and create the grids. Any ideas?

Comment: You should be able to run it fairly easily using the Kriging geoprocessing tool.  Open up ArcToolbox, navigate to Spatial Analyst > Interpolation > Kriging.  

Is there a specific error you've been having?

Comment: BTW you would need the spatial analyst extension and ArcEditor if I am not mistaken, to run that.

Comment: Nobody who understands kriging would use SA to do it--upon examination they would find it's simply not up to the task--but they could seriously consider ESRI's Geostatistical Analyst, which supports the data analysis, variography, and (I believe) the cross-validation that are necessary to do kriging right.

Comment: The problem is since values in between 25m interval do not have interpolated coordinates values, they are assumed to have 0,0 and the kriging does not run. These are thousands of points so it will be helpful if I could be able to automate the interpolation of the coordinates within argis

Answer (score 1):

In ArcGIS, there are the following options:

1. [Spatial Analyst; Interpolation toolset; Kriging](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z0000006n000000) (type: [KrigingModelOrdinary](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/KrigingModelOrdinary/005m00000054000000/))

and the one recommended by whuber:

2. [Geostatistical Analyst](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//003100000003000000); [Geostatistical Wizard; Geostatistical Methods; Ordinary](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/A_quick_tour_of_Geostatistical_Analyst/003100000004000000/GUID-EA09C97B-1356-4353-B652-C17CA8C592BF/)